# Xamarin Forms and IEventAggregator

Tags: xamarin.forms

Making my APP for my job I'm getting stuck on a problem:

I have a base page to fill with information for an order
1 Client
2 Destination
3 Article

When I tap on a button I get a new page (different for what I'm serching Client, Destination, Article) with a listview of the item. On a tap of the item I would like to pass the parameter to the main page to compile the order.
I think that the better solution is to implement the IEventAggregator of PRISM, I have made also some test and it work with button, but if I try to put it on the itemtapped, it give me error.

I have created the class for the event to pass the payload.

This is the xaml.cs of the page that (in theory) must pass the selected client to the mainpage:

```
        IEventAggregator _ea;
    private Cliente cliente_selezionato = new Cliente();

    ...

    public void TapCliente(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e, IEventAggregator ea )
    {
        cliente_selezionato = (Cliente)
         ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
        _ea.GetEvent<CambioClienteEvent>().Publish(cliente_selezionato);
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DatiTestataOC());
    }
```

On the mainpage viewmodel I have:

```
        public DatiTestataOCViewModel(IEventAggregator ea)
    {
        ea.GetEvent<CambioClienteEvent>().Subscribe(NuovoCliente);
    }

    private void NuovoCliente(Cliente Parameter)
    {
        Cliente = Parameter;
    }
```

The error that I get are:
Errore  XFC0002 EventHandler "TapCliente" with correct signature not found in type "Mokadroid.Views.SceltaClientePage".
Errore  XFC0004 Missing default constructor for "Mokadroid.ViewModels.DatiTestataOCViewModel".

If you have Other solution more easy to implement I'm Open...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've understand that I can't simply use that part of the package, I need to start a new template using the prism template and use all the package.